# Check if letter clicked and left button mouse is down win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

I want to listen if left mouse button is clicked and a letter too for example 'a'

I already did that for only the mouse click, I can't listen for both 
I tried the following code but didn't work for me

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    if(GetKeyState('a') & 0x8000)
    {
        SetPixel(hdc, LOWORD(lp), HIWORD(lp), red);
    }
    x = LOWORD(lp);
    y = HIWORD(lp);
    for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < 200; j++)
            SetPixel(hdc, x + i, y + j, red);

break;
```

If i click the left button it draws the shape, but if i tried to do while 'a' is pressed it do no thing

Comment: `'a'` is `0x61` which is `VK_NUMPAD1`. The virtual key code for the A key is `'A'`. Also, you want `GetKeyState`, not `GetAsyncKeyState` to avoid race conditions if the user presses A, then clicks the mousse, then releases A before your mouse handler can run. Finally, you are drawing outside your paint handler, which means that your paint code will erase whatever you draw here.

Comment: You should call `ReleaseDC` with `hdc` after done using it.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried  if(GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000) but didn't work too!, and I'm already using GetKeyState not async, also my program is drawing well except for this issue, nothing is outside handler!!

Comment: @VTT I did but changed nothing!

Comment: If you change `a` to `A` and put the stuff after `x = LOWORD(lp);` into `else` block then you should see dot appearing when you click and press `A`. Right now you draw huge square next a dot so it may be hard to spot it. `ReleaseDC` is required to prevent resource leak.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague. What specifically doesn't work? Does the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message never get received? Does `GetDC` fail to get a DC? Does `GeyKeyState('A')` return a value that does not have bit 15 set? Does `SetPixel` execute but fail to draw a pixel?

Comment: Why you do not use `FillRect` to create solid color rectangle which is much faster than ~40,000 calls to `SetPixel`? And what is the goal here - to have red rectangle at mouse click (always) plus 1 pixel at upper left when key `a` is down?

Answer (score 0):

Catch `WM_KEYDOWN` and when the key is letter (`'a'`) check the mouse button with `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)`. Or in your example, check for `'a'` again with `GetAsyncKeyState` not `GetKeyState`.

Comment: I tried to change GetKeyState to GetAsyncKeyState but it didn't work too!! and how to use your first suggestion, I didn't catch it all

Comment: Use `0x41` for key A not `0x61`. The key A is always `0x41` and the upper or lower case are additional attribute. My first suggestion is little different than your way - to use it you have to click the mouse without any action and do the job when press `'a'`.

Comment: I already changed it to if(GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000) but still nothing is working if i pressed a when mouse click!!!